# How to filter a list in angular js by sublevels of object

Tags: angularjs, ng-filter

I received a list of objects from server in something like this

```
[
    {id: 'a', checked :true,test:{sub:{var:4}}}, 
    {id: 'b', checked:true,test:{sub:{var:3}}},
    {id: 'c', checked:true,test:{sub:{var:2}}},
    {id: 'd', checked:true,test:{sub:{var:2}}},
    {id: 'e', checked:true,test:{sub:{var:3}}}
]
```

Now I want to want to filter this list on the basis of "var". I am doing something like:

```
    <div ng-controller="repeatCtrl">
   <div ng:repeat="o in list | filter: {test.sub.var : myPrecious.id}">
       {{o.id}}: 
       <input type="checkbox" ng:model="o.checked" />
       {{o.checked}}
    </div>
</div>
```

my controller code is like

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('repeatCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.list = [
        {id: 'a', checked :true,test:{sub:{var:4}}}, 
        {id: 'b', checked:true,test:{sub:{var:3}}},
        {id: 'c', checked:true,test:{sub:{var:2}}},
        {id: 'd', checked:true,test:{sub:{var:2}}},
        {id: 'e', checked:true,test:{sub:{var:3}}}
    ];

    $scope.myPrecious = 2;
});
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [solution](https://plnkr.co/edit/GfzDbUMMr7CoTPSgomjX?p=preview). You can just specify `{$ : myPrecious.id}` at `filter` without worrying about hierarchy level, as said at [docs.angularjs.org](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter): *special property name ($ by default) can be used (e.g. as in {$: "text"}) to accept a match against any property of the object or its **nested** object properties*:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-repeat="o in list | filter : {$ : myPrecious.id}">
    {{o.id}}
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="o.checked" />
    {{o.checked}}
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$scope.list = [
    {id: 'a', checked:true,test:{sub:{var:4}}}, 
    {id: 'b', checked:true,test:{sub:{var:3}}},
    {id: 'c', checked:true,test:{sub:{var:2}}},
    {id: 'd', checked:true,test:{sub:{var:2}}},
    {id: 'e', checked:true,test:{sub:{var:3}}}
];

$scope.myPrecious = {id:2};
```